# Exclude empty Arrays from Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am building JSON from Java object tree using [Jackson ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html). Some of my Java objects are collections and sometimes they might be empty. So if they are empty that ObjectMapper generates me: `"attributes": [],` and I want to exclude those kind of empty JSON arrays from my result. My current ObjectMapper config:

```
SerializationConfig config = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig();
config.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
config.set(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899115/how-to-not-send-an-empty-collection-in-jackson) I've read that I can use:

```
config.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT);
```

But that is generating me an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.mycomp.assessments.evaluation.EvaluationImpl$1 has no default constructor; can not instantiate default bean value to support 'properties=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT' annotation.
```

So how should I prevent those empty arrays to appear in my result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use:

```
config.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY);
```

for Jackson 1 or

```
config.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

for Jackson 2

Comment: I am using Jackson: 1.8.5, but there is not such option: JsonSerialize.Includsion.NON_EMPTY. There is only: ALWAYS, NON_NULL, NON_DEFAULT

Comment: Fixed a type (Inclusion rather than Incudsion), but you need at least Jackson 1.9 to use it I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the version of Jackson and thats fine now :)

Answer (score 4):

A very good example describing :

- JsonInclude.Include.**NON_NULL**
- JsonInclude.Include.**ABSENT**
- JsonInclude.Include.**NON_EMPTY**

In : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-non-empty.html

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private String dept;
  private String address;
  private List<String> phones;
  private AtomicReference<BigDecimal> salary;
    .............
}

public class ExampleMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Employee employee = new Employee();
      employee.setName("Trish");
      employee.setDept("");
      employee.setAddress(null);
      employee.setPhones(new ArrayList<>());
      employee.setSalary(new AtomicReference<>());

      ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonString = om.writeValueAsString(employee);
      System.out.println(jsonString);
  }
}
```

=====> Result :

If we don't use @JsonInclude annotation at all then output of the above example will be:
{"name":"Trish","dept":"","address":null,"phones":[],"salary":null}

If we use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.**NON_NULL**) on Employee class then output will be:
{"name":"Trish","dept":"","phones":[],"salary":null}

If we use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.**NON_ABSENT**) then output will be:
{"name":"Trish","dept":"","phones":[]}

If we use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.**NON_EMPTY**) :
{"name":"Trish"}

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the object to be serialized, you can also place an annotation directly on the field, for example (Jackson 2.11.2):

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
```

In this way, no further configuration of the `ObjectMapper` is required.