# Cleaning empty fields from generic JSON before writing it again into JSON

Tags: json, jackson

My function needs to take an input String that can represent any kind of JSON object, clean the empty fields and transform it back to a String.

Given this input JSON, I like the `doors` field to be removed:

```
String carJson = "{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : \"\"}";
```

I was trying to work with `Jackson` and this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) and got this:

```
  private static void jacksonConvert(String inputJSON) throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY); // tried each of the 3 options. Non of them worked
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    Object jacksonObj = mapper.readValue(inputJSON, Object.class);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jacksonObj);
    System.out.println(json);  // {"brand":"Mercedes","doors":""}  why "doors" is here?
}
```

Yet, the `doors` field keeps on coming out in the output...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this great working example](https://technicaldifficulties.io/2018/04/26/using-jackson-to-remove-empty-json-fields/) that I will copy to here for future generations.

One small adjustment for STACIE's blog, is that I updated the block of

```
      else if (value instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ret.set(key, removeEmptyFields((ArrayNode)value));
        }
```

to also catch and remove empty arrays:

```
     else if (value instanceof ArrayNode) {
            if (value.size() > 0){
                ret.set(key, removeEmptyFields((ArrayNode)value));
            }
        }
```

And the full working code is this:

```
public static String removeEmptyElements(String json){

    try{

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode before = mapper.readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);
        ObjectNode after = removeEmptyFields(before);

        String afterString = mapper.writeValueAsString(after);
        return afterString;
    }catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        log.error("Error while cleaning json: {}", e.getMessage());
        return json;
    }
}


private static ObjectNode removeEmptyFields(final ObjectNode jsonNode) {
    ObjectNode ret = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = jsonNode.fields();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
        String key = entry.getKey();
        JsonNode value = entry.getValue();

        if (value instanceof ObjectNode) {
            Map<String, ObjectNode> map = new HashMap<String, ObjectNode>();
            map.put(key, removeEmptyFields((ObjectNode)value));
            ret.setAll(map);
        }
        else if (value instanceof ArrayNode) {
            if (value.size() > 0){
                ret.set(key, removeEmptyFields((ArrayNode)value));
            }
        }
        else if (value.asText() != null && !value.asText().isEmpty()) {
            ret.set(key, value);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


private static ArrayNode removeEmptyFields(ArrayNode array) {
    ArrayNode ret = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();
    Iterator<JsonNode> iter = array.elements();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode value = iter.next();

        if (value instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ret.add(removeEmptyFields((ArrayNode)(value)));
        }
        else if (value instanceof ObjectNode) {
            ret.add(removeEmptyFields((ObjectNode)(value)));
        }
        else if (value != null && !value.textValue().isEmpty()){
            ret.add(value);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation states](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) that these enumerations are used...

> to define which properties of Java Beans are to be included in
>   serialization

However, if you're serialising to an `Object` Jackson will instantiate that object as a `Map`.  Map entries are not considered properties.  Therefore the `Json.Include` doesn't apply.

**Edit**

There's an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159596/how-do-i-remove-empty-json-nodes-in-java-with-jackson) about removing empty nodes (if you serialise it as a `JsonNode` but none of the answers strike me as particularly performant.